# get value of dynamically created input

Tags: jquery, pug

This is the code generated automatically according the information that is in the database

```
   each p in posts              
    .w3-container.w3-card.w3-black.w3-round.w3-margin
        p= p.title
        input(type='hidden', id="idPost" value=p._id)
        if p.picture
            img.w3-margin-bottom(src="images/"+p.picture style="width:100%")
        p= p.content
        .w3-container.w3-card(id="commentSection") 
            if p.comments
                each m in p.comments
                    p= m.user.split(":")[1] + "        "+ m.message
        textarea(id="NewComment", cols="80%", rows="1" placeholder="Enter a new comment")
```

I'm trying in get the value of the input `idPost` but so far not lucky. I tried some approaches like `$('[id=idPost]').eq(2).val()` but in this case I need to know previous which index it is and I don't.

I tried also something like this that I think is what I want but I'm not getting it to work

```
var num = $(this).closest('w3-container').find(".idPost").val();
```

This one I'm searching for class instead of id that is shown in the code above but neither of these work.

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: `.find(".idPost")` looks for a class named `idPost` but there's no such class

Comment: thats what i said in the last sentence. i tried with id(#idPost) and with class(.idPost). both didnt work

Comment: $('input[type=hidden]').val()

Comment: @Mirko Acimovic doenst work either. Just return the same element no matter wich i choose

Comment: if DOM is not loaded you need to put it in $(document).ready(function() { }) block.

Comment: _"Just return the same element no matter wich i choose"_ because id's have to be **unique**

Answer (score 0):

input(type='hidden', id="idPost" value=p._id)

here idPost is input id so you need to find #idPost

var num = $(this).parents('.w3-container').find("#idPost").val();

Answer (score 0):

Because neither of the solutions where working i tried something and it worked

pug

```
each p in posts              
            .w3-container.w3-card.w3-black.w3-round.w3-margin
                p= p.title 
                if p.picture
                    img.w3-margin-bottom(src="images/"+p.picture style="width:100%")
                p= p.content
                .w3-container.w3-card(class="commentSection" name=p._id) 
                    if p.comments
                        each m in p.comments
                            p= m.user.split(":")[1] + "        "+ m.message
                textarea(id="NewComment", cols="80%", rows="1" placeholder="Enter a new comment")
```

Now in my jquery i just get the current textarea that i press "enter" and then will loop all the "containers" with the class commentSection and check if the attribute name of the current textarea matches the right one of the commentSection. If true then im in the right place and can do the rest.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var targetInput = $(e.target);
      if(targetInput.is('textarea')) { 
         if(e.which == 13){ 
           e.preventDefault();
           $('.commentSection').each(function() {
               if($(this).attr("name")==targetInput.attr('name')){
                $(this).append('<p>'+targetInput.val()+'</p>');
               }
            }); 
          // $("#commentSection").append('<p>'+targetInput.val()+'</p>');
           ajaxPost(targetInput.val(),targetInput.attr('name'),
           p=> alert(JSON.stringify(p)),
           e =>{
               alert('AJAX ERROR:'+JSON.stringify(e));
               console.log("AJAX ERROR:"+JSON.stringify(e));
           });
           targetInput.val('');
      }
       }
   });
```

Bit scrappy but it works